# Why doesn't the C++ last draft allow a type "noexcept function" to be reference compatible with a type "noexcept function"?

Tags: c++, reference, language-lawyer, c++17

For instance, see [[dcl.init.ref]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.ref#4):

> Given types “ cv1 T1” and “ cv2 T2”, “ cv1 T1” is reference-related to
>   “ cv2 T2” if T1 is the same type as T2, or T1 is a base class of T2. “
>   cv1 T1” is reference-compatible with “ cv2 T2” if
>
> - T1 is reference-related to T2, or
> - T2 is “noexcept function” and T1 is “function”, where the function types are otherwise the same,
>
> and cv1 is the same cv-qualification as, or greater cv-qualification
>   than, cv2. In all cases where the reference-related or
>   reference-compatible relationship of two types is used to establish
>   the validity of a reference binding, and T1 is a base class of T2, a
>   program that necessitates such a binding is ill-formed if T1 is an
>   inaccessible (Clause [class.access]) or ambiguous
>   ([class.member.lookup]) base class of T2.

I may be missing something, but my reading of the second bullet point above tells me that a "noexcept function" (T2) should not bind to a reference of type "noexcept function" (T1). But the snippet below compiles in [clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/50456f1747d58d4b) and g++.

```
int g(int) noexcept;
int (&rg)(int) noexcept = g;
```

Comment: Aren't the types in your example reference-related (by being identical), thus satisfying the first bullet point?

Comment: @Columbo Good catch, tks.

Comment: Cannot reproduce, since the cited paragraph clearly does allow it. Also, this isn't C++14.

Comment: @T.C. It does allow it because of the first bullet point, not because of the second, as Columbo precisely told me. Also, I selected `C++1z`, but somehow it got replaced by C++14. I don't know why!